# flow complaining about defaultProps on connected component

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a connected component like this:

```
const ConnectedComponent = connect((state, props) => {
  return {
     //fields
  };
}, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);

ConnectedComponent.defaultProps = {
  // fields
};
```

But flow says:

```
ConnectedComponent.defaultProps = {
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment of property `defaultProps`
 ConnectedComponent.defaultProps = {
142: };
     ^ object literal. This type is incompatible with
139: ConnectedComponent.defaultProps = {
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply `defaultProps` to a component which doesn't extend `React.Component`.

Also, in your case your `ConnectedComponent` is directly connected to store, so there are no props whereas the component `Component` will receive props from `ConnectedComponent`, so you should add default props over `Component` to set default values.

```js
const ConnectedComponent = connect((state, props) => {
  return {
     //fields
  };
}, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);


//This should be added to the Component wherever it is declared
Component.defaultProps = {
  // fields
};
```

Let me know if it helps.